# how to enter a carriage return in a Link label field

Tags: xpages

I've got several Link fields on an xPage. The labels of these link fields are retrieved from a Notes document. I want to insert a carriage return into the text so the text when displayed on the web page is split into 2 lines. Entering

```
<br/>
```

used to work for label fields so I tried that but it doesn't work anymore. Maybe some xpage update changed that functionality. Anyone know another way of doing this?

thanks clem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `escape` property to false in order to allow HTML. Here's an example:

```
<xp:link escape="false" id="test" value="http://example.com">
    <xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Test 1<br/>Test 2"}]]></xp:this.text>
</xp:link>
```